# AWS ElasticSearch CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-cloudformation

Advanced cluster settings

- Request body index: true
- Field data cache allocation: 20
- clause maximum count: 1024

How do I configure these using CloudFormation, I have tried

```
  AdvancedClusterSettings:
    RequestBodyIndex: true
    FieldDataCacheAllocation: 20
    ClauseMaximumCount: 1024
```

But this is giving the following error:
Encountered unsupported property AdvancedClusterSettings

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/configuration-api.html), try:

```
  AdvancedOptions:
    "rest.action.multi.allow_explicit_index": "true|false",
    "indices.fielddata.cache.size": "40",
    "indices.query.bool.max_clause_count": "1024",
    "override_main_response_version": "true|false"
```